# How to link ODBC libraries to Ecplise for C on Windows?

Tags: c, eclipse, odbc

I need to build a C language Eclipse project that connects to a local MySQL db.
I have also ODBC installed on my W11 machine (it allows creating a DSN using MySQL driver).

I cannot build the project (I think its because I don't know how to link the "lodbc" library to the project, not even where it can be).
Under the MySQL folder I have a "Connector ODBC 8.0" folder and I tried adding that folder to the library search path and the myodbc8w.dll file itself.

But I get error messages that the code cannot be compiled like:

```
c:\mingw\include\sqltypes.h:17:9: error: unknown type name 'ULONG'
 typedef ULONG UDWORD;
         ^~~~~
c:\mingw\include\sqltypes.h:18:9: error: unknown type name 'USHORT'
 typedef USHORT UWORD;
         ^~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\sqltypes.h:24:9: error: unknown type name 'PVOID'
 typedef PVOID PTR;
         ^~~~~
c:\mingw\include\sqltypes.h:25:9: error: unknown type name 'PVOID'
 typedef PVOID HENV;
         ^~~~~
c:\mingw\include\sqltypes.h:26:9: error: unknown type name 'PVOID'
 typedef PVOID HDBC;
         ^~~~~
c:\mingw\include\sqltypes.h:27:9: error: unknown type name 'PVOID'
 typedef PVOID HSTMT;
         ^~~~~
c:\mingw\include\sqltypes.h:29:9: error: unknown type name 'UCHAR'
 typedef UCHAR SQLCHAR;
         ^~~~~
c:\mingw\include\sqltypes.h:37:9: error: unknown type name 'PVOID'
 typedef PVOID SQLPOINTER;
         ^~~~~
c:\mingw\include\sqltypes.h:50:9: error: unknown type name 'HWND'
 typedef HWND SQLHWND;
         ^~~~
c:\mingw\include\sqltypes.h:51:9: error: unknown type name 'ULONG'
 typedef ULONG BOOKMARK;
         ^~~~~
c:\mingw\include\sqltypes.h:154:5: error: unknown type name 'DWORD'
     DWORD Data1;
     ^~~~~
c:\mingw\include\sqltypes.h:155:5: error: unknown type name 'WORD'
     WORD Data2;
     ^~~~
c:\mingw\include\sqltypes.h:156:5: error: unknown type name 'WORD'
     WORD Data3;
     ^~~~
c:\mingw\include\sqltypes.h:157:5: error: unknown type name 'BYTE'
     BYTE Data4[ 8 ];
     ^~~~
In file included from ..\src\BuenasMadrugadas.c:13:0:
c:\mingw\include\sqlext.h:1203:15: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'ODBCGetTryWaitValue'
 DWORD SQL_API ODBCGetTryWaitValue(void);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\sqlext.h:1204:14: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'ODBCSetTryWaitValue'
 BOOL SQL_API ODBCSetTryWaitValue(DWORD);
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\sqlext.h:1207:14: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'TraceReturn'
 VOID SQL_API TraceReturn(RETCODE,RETCODE);
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\sqlext.h:1208:15: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'TraceVersion'
 DWORD SQL_API TraceVersion(void);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
..\src\BuenasMadrugadas.c: In function 'main':
..\src\BuenasMadrugadas.c:24:45: warning: passing argument 3 of 'SQLSetEnvAttr' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   SQLSetEnvAttr(env, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void *) SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
                                             ^
In file included from ..\src\BuenasMadrugadas.c:12:0:
c:\mingw\include\sql.h:401:19: note: expected 'SQLPOINTER {aka int}' but argument is of type 'void *'
 SQLRETURN SQL_API SQLSetEnvAttr(SQLHENV,SQLINTEGER,SQLPOINTER,SQLINTEGER);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
..\src\BuenasMadrugadas.c:28:31: warning: passing argument 2 of 'SQLDriverConnect' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   ret = SQLDriverConnect(dbc, NULL, "DSN=DSN_prueba;", SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);
                               ^~~~
In file included from ..\src\BuenasMadrugadas.c:13:0:
c:\mingw\include\sqlext.h:1184:19: note: expected 'SQLHWND {aka int}' but argument is of type 'void *'
 SQLRETURN SQL_API SQLDriverConnect(SQLHDBC,SQLHWND,SQLCHAR*,SQLSMALLINT,SQLCHAR*,SQLSMALLINT,SQLSMALLINT*,SQLUSMALLINT);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
..\src\BuenasMadrugadas.c:28:37: warning: passing argument 3 of 'SQLDriverConnect' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   ret = SQLDriverConnect(dbc, NULL, "DSN=DSN_prueba;", SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ..\src\BuenasMadrugadas.c:13:0:
c:\mingw\include\sqlext.h:1184:19: note: expected 'SQLCHAR * {aka int *}' but argument is of type 'char *'
 SQLRETURN SQL_API SQLDriverConnect(SQLHDBC,SQLHWND,SQLCHAR*,SQLSMALLINT,SQLCHAR*,SQLSMALLINT,SQLSMALLINT*,SQLUSMALLINT);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
..\src\BuenasMadrugadas.c:42:31: warning: passing argument 2 of 'SQLExecDirect' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     ret = SQLExecDirect(stmt, consulta, SQL_NTS);
                               ^~~~~~~~
In file included from ..\src\BuenasMadrugadas.c:12:0:
c:\mingw\include\sql.h:352:19: note: expected 'SQLCHAR * {aka int *}' but argument is of type 'char *'
 SQLRETURN SQL_API SQLExecDirect(SQLHSTMT,SQLCHAR*,SQLINTEGER);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
..\src\BuenasMadrugadas.c:54:47: warning: passing argument 4 of 'SQLGetData' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         ret = SQLGetData(stmt, i, SQL_C_CHAR, buf, 1024, &nIdicator);
                                               ^~~
In file included from ..\src\BuenasMadrugadas.c:12:0:
c:\mingw\include\sql.h:367:19: note: expected 'SQLPOINTER {aka int}' but argument is of type 'SQLCHAR * {aka int *}'
 SQLRETURN SQL_API SQLGetData(SQLHSTMT,SQLUSMALLINT,SQLSMALLINT,SQLPOINTER,SQLLEN,SQLLEN*);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~
..\src\BuenasMadrugadas.c:57:30: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'SQLCHAR * {aka int *}' [-Wformat=]
           printf("* Columna %s", buf);
                              ^

12:06:36 Build Failed. 18 errors, 6 warnings. (took 86ms)
```

Comment: Fyi, that's not a linking problem; that's a compile-problem. this looks like someone didn't setup the dependency to windows.h

Comment: I don't understand. The code compiles on Ubuntu simply by adding "-lodbc" to the gcc command. In any case, how could I have it compiled in my Eclipse for W11 IDE?